# Live id authentication for asp.net MVC site redirect uri not valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to user live id authentication in my asp.net web application.
I followed the steps in the below post

http://www.benday.com/2014/02/25/walkthrough-asp-net-mvc-identity-with-microsoft-account-authentication/

creating the application and setting up domain in local host are working fine.
Setting the redirect url in app settings is an issue. When i run the app it prompts an error

*"The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. 
The expected value is 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf' or a URL which matches the redirect URI registered for this client application."*

i tried "http://www.mysampleapp.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback" and "http://www.mysampleapp.com/signin-microsoft." and the urls it did not work. (mysampleapp being the url i hosted locally)

When i click on "Microsoft" in the external authentication part i am directed to the below url

```
"https://login.live.com/err.srflc=1033#error=invalid_request&error
_description=The%20provided%20value%20for%20the%20input%20parameter%20'redirect_uri'%
20is%20not%20valid.%20The%20expected%20value%20is%20'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf
'%20or%20a%20URL%20which%20matches%20the%20redirect%20URI%20registered%20for
%20this%20client%20application."
```

Any way to find out the url?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using new Microsoft live application settings
then Redirect URLs: http://something.yourDomain.com/signin-microsoft

If you are using old Microsoft live application settings
then Redirect URLs: http://something.yourDomain.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback

**Note that:** 'something' should not be www.

Don't use www, replace it with some kind of sub domain name and set it properly on host file. Thats how I got this work in my previous project to test this locally.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Try to put this `http://myapp-url/signin-microsoft` to Set the Redirect URLs.

Comment: How is this url different from the one i have mentioned in the question? it doesnt work for me

Comment: If it is not working then use something like firebug to see what the request to the oauth provider looks like and then whatever the redirect uri is inside of that request is what you need to use..